# android - Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24701 (FinalizerDaemon) error with google breakpad dump

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-webview

My app will randomly crash and give these same error logs every time. Why am I not getting any native stack trace or debugging log? It happens as certain WebView elements in my app load but I'm not sure what this error means.

```
A/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Wrong thread!
D/video﹕ New article fragment created at:6
W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad﹕ Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad﹕ playstore-debug
W/google-breakpad﹕ 1
W/google-breakpad﹕ 92675e2e-3e24-4fdd-9bc9-d979deace950
W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
E/chromium﹕ ### WebView Version 43.0.2357.121 (code 2357121)
--------- beginning of crash
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24701 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

Is anyone familiar with these types of errors or have seen these ones in particular before?

Comment: I have the same issue and it happens only on a Nexus 7. did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet. I'm seeing this issue on Nexus 9, Nexus 10 also. I have a feeling it might be related to this since I can't find anything wrong on the native side: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481420. Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: Just to clarify, I have also primarily seen this issue on my Nexus 7 but it can happen on 9 and 10 also.